# How to access fragment variable from other class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have a Fragment `NewsFragment`in which I define an `AlertDialog`. I want to access the `AlertDialog` to close it after on click on the item. However I cannot access it.

I found this code on the internet and it works fine but with an Activity not with a Fragment.

```
((NewsFragment) context).alertDialogNews.cancel();

public class OnItemClickListenerListViewItem implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //Context context = view.getContext();
        Context context = view.getContext();

        TextView textViewItem = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem));

        // get the clicked item name
        String listItemText = textViewItem.getText().toString();

        // get the clicked item ID
        String listItemId = textViewItem.getTag().toString();

        // just toast it
        // Toast.makeText(context, "Item: " + listItemText + ", Item ID: " + listItemId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //((MainActivity) context).alertDialogStores.cancel();
        ((NewsFragment) context).alertDialogNews.cancel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways to do that. The easiest is probably to pass either the `NewsFragment` or the `Dialog` as a parameter in the `OnItemClickListenerListViewItem` constructor.

```
public class OnItemClickListenerListViewItem implements OnItemClickListener {
    private NewsFragment mNewsFragment;

    public OnItemClickListenerListViewItem(NewsFragment nf){
        mNewsFragment = nf;
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a `Fragment` is not a `Context`. Thus the View's Context that you retrieve through `view.getContext()` is not your `NewsFragment`.

You will need to find another method of referencing your AlertDialog from your `OnItemClickListenerListViewItem`.

One possible approach would be to add the Fragment to the listener's constructor like so:

```
public class OnItemClickListenerListViewItem implements OnItemClickListener {
    private AlertDialog mAlertDialog;

    public OnItemClickLIstenerListViewItem(AlertDialog dialog) {
        mAlertDialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Do your click logic

        mAlertDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```